# Saving EEPROM after programming on Arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom, programmer

I am using an Arduino Uno,  and I use the EEPROM to store some presets. It works fine. But, when I reprogram the Arduino, the EEPROM gets wiped out. Is there a way to prevent this, and have the EEPROM not change after the Arduino is programmed?

I am using a USBtinyISP programmer.

Thank you very much for your help, and advance.

Here is the verbose result of my programming:

```
Sketch uses 5,298 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 286 bytes (13%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,762 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
/Users/fed/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/bin/avrdude -C/Users/fed/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cusbtiny -Uflash:w:/var/folders/lb/5zdjdm6153jcx_5nq32tt7gw0000gn/T/buildb926e4430d002b65d0ca44bda9d693e2.tmp/LED_strip_08.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:01:35
        Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
        Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

        System wide configuration file is "/Users/fed/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf"
        User configuration file is "/Users/fed/.avrduderc"
        User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

        Using Port                    : usb
        Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: 006:003
        AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
        Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
        PAGEL                         : PD7
        BS2                           : PC2
        RESET disposition             : dedicated
        RETRY pulse                   : SCK
        serial program mode           : yes
        parallel program mode         : yes
        Timeout                       : 200
        StabDelay                     : 100
        CmdexeDelay                   : 25
        SyncLoops                     : 32
        ByteDelay                     : 0
        PollIndex                     : 3
        PollValue                     : 0x53
        Memory Detail                 :

                                 Block Poll               Page                       Polled
          Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
          ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
          eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
          flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
          lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
          hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
          efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
          lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
          calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
          signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

        Programmer Type : USBtiny
        Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
        To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: reading input file "/var/folders/lb/5zdjdm6153jcx_5nq32tt7gw0000gn/T/buildb926e4430d002b65d0ca44bda9d693e2.tmp/LED_strip_08.ino.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (5298 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 7.80s

avrdude: 5298 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against /var/folders/lb/5zdjdm6153jcx_5nq32tt7gw0000gn/T/buildb926e4430d002b65d0ca44bda9d693e2.tmp/LED_strip_08.ino.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file /var/folders/lb/5zdjdm6153jcx_5nq32tt7gw0000gn/T/buildb926e4430d002b65d0ca44bda9d693e2.tmp/LED_strip_08.ino.hex:
avrdude: input file /var/folders/lb/5zdjdm6153jcx_5nq32tt7gw0000gn/T/buildb926e4430d002b65d0ca44bda9d693e2.tmp/LED_strip_08.ino.hex contains 5298 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 4.98s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 5298 bytes of flash verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: I believe avrdude allows access to each type of memory independently, so this is probably an issue with the commands the IDE issues.  Another option is to use avrdude to backup the eeprom and then re-write it after.  Basically you need to become familiar with avrdude and figure out how you can change the way the IDE uses it.  Or else only have the IDE build your sketch, and use avrdude manually to load it.

Comment: I should clarify my previous comment was more about using avrdude for ISP; off the top of my head, I'm not sure what subset of this the bootloader supports.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the fuses for `Atmega328` to preserve `EEPROM` during chip erase (for `ISP` programming). Basically, if you are using `USBTiny` connected to the `UNO` by `3x2` pin header, you are using `ISP programming`. Which means chip erase erases also `EEPROM` if fuse `EESAVE` is `1` (unprogrammed).

Uploading over the **`Arduino bootloader`** (it means you have the `UNO` connected directly into the computer and there is no other device like `USBTiny`). The `EEPROM` should be preserved then.

Comment: So, are you saying that changing fuses (I have no idea how to do that) may or may not work.  But not using Arduino IDE, but rather using AVRdude in  command line should work?

Comment: @Fed EEPROM can be changed by avrdude but Arduino usually won't do anything with it (you can see whole command in the Arduino IDE if you enable verbose upload).

Comment: I updated the verbose output of Arduino IDE when I program the Arduino.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @fed The most important thing is USBTiny - it performs chip erase and without EESAVE fuse programmed to 0, it erases EEPROM too.